Нужна ли запятая после "внутри" в этом предложении?
Помните, что красота начинается внутри(?) и забота о своем здоровье – это первый шаг к тому, чтобы выглядеть хорошо.

Правильно:
(1) Помните, (2) что красота начинается внутри, и (3) забота о своем здоровье – это первый шаг к тому, (4) чтобы выглядеть хорошо.
Пояснение
Это сложное предложение, четыре грамматические основы. Но надо правильно определить структуру предложения: есть ли здесь СПП с однородными изъяснительными придаточными.
Очевидно, что нет, так как предложение (4) является придаточным цели по отношению к предложению (3), то есть  однородных изъяснительных придаточных нет. Поэтому запятая ставится.
О грамматике предложения
Таким образом, это сложное предложение, состоящее из двух СПП  (придаточное изъяснительное и придаточное цели), связанных союзом И.

Спасибо! А почему нельзя понять так? Помните: 1) красота начинается внутри, 2) забота о своем здоровье – это первый шаг к тому, чтобы выглядеть хорошо. И то и то надо помнить.

Тогда надо написать так: Помните, что красота начинается внутри и важно заботиться о своем здоровье. Это будут  однородные изъяснительные придаточные. В нашем же случае предложение (3) не  простое,  а сложное.
